# How to write condition in struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct

Based on condition, how to set Array of Dictionary else only Dictionary for struct.

```
   struct Data {
        let id: String?
        let name: String?
        let subData:  Environment.Dev == "Dev_URL" ? [SubData]? : SubData?
    
        init(_ json: JSON) {
            id = json["id"].stringValue
            name = json["name"].stringValue
            subData =  Environment.Dev == "Dev_URL" ? json["sub_data"].arrayValue.map { SubData($0) } : SubData(json["sub_data"])
        }
    }
```

// SubData Struct

```
   struct SubData {
        let id: String?
        init(_ json: JSON) {
            id = json["id"].stringValue
   }
}
```

My response structure changes due to environment changes.

How to set struct Data for let subData [SubData] i.e array of dictionary else SubData normal dictionary based on Dev or other.

Comment: You cannot change type of a variable depending on a runtime condition.

Comment: Use an enum with associated values, where one case has `SubData` as its associated type and the other has `[SubData]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to make it array in both cases as type can't be determined at runtime

```
let subData:[SubData]?
```

Then

```
subData =  Environment.Dev == "Dev_URL"              
            ? json["sub_data"].arrayValue.map { SubData($0) }
            : [SubData(json["sub_data"])]
```

Also you can change your response `sub_data` to be an array in both cases so above line be

```
subData = json["sub_data"].arrayValue.map { SubData($0) }
```

That way you work in development and release smoothly

Comment: @thanks khan. is  sh_ Shah Rukh?